# Can't find solution for rust error " Error("EOF while parsing an object", line: 1, column: 1)"

Tags: mysql, json, rust

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{prelude::*, BufReader};
use serde_json::{Value};

use mysql::*;
use mysql::prelude::*;

struct Show {
    title: String,
    show_poster: String,
    show_url: String,
}

fn main() {
    // Open and read the file lines
    let path = r"C:\Users\egete\Desktop\projects\cdeneme\rust\mysqljson\src\info.json";
    let file = File::open(path).expect("Unable to read file");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let lines: Vec<String> = reader.lines().map(|l| l.expect("Could not parse line")).collect();

    // Connect to your my-sql database
    let url = Opts::from_url("mysql://root:Egetelli99@localhost:3306/jsonmysql").unwrap();
    let pool = Pool::new(url).unwrap();
    let mut conn = pool.get_conn().unwrap();

    // Loop through the lines
    for line in lines {

        // Parse the line into a JSON object serde_json::Value
        let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(&line).expect("Unable to parse");

        // Since we want to save the streaming services of the said show, we need to 
        // loop an array inside the JSON file.
        let l = v["watchAvailability"][0]["directUrls"].as_array().unwrap().len();
        for n in 0..l {
            let streaming_url = v["watchAvailability"][0]["directUrls"][n].as_str().clone();
            match streaming_url {
                Some(url) => {
                    // Display the streaming url.  I have to do this to remove the Some(url) warning. 
                    // Unused variables in Rust emits warnings
                    println!("{:?}", url);

                    // Create a vector (array of object).  
                    // This provides you the ability to process multiple objects upon saving
                    let shows = vec![
                        Show { 
                            title: v["title"].as_str().as_deref().unwrap_or("Error").to_string(),
                            show_poster: v["posterPath"].as_str().as_deref().unwrap_or("Error").to_string(),
                            show_url: v["watchAvailability"][0]["directUrls"][n].as_str().as_deref().unwrap_or("Error").to_string(),
                        },
                    ];  
                    //Execute an insert query
                    conn.exec_batch(
                        r"INSERT INTO `shows` (`title`, `show_poster`, `show_url`)
                        VALUES (:title, :show_poster, :show_url)",
                    shows.iter().map(|s| params! {
                        "title" => s.title.clone(),
                        "show_poster" => s.show_poster.clone(),
                        "show_url" => s.show_url.clone(),
                        })
                    ).unwrap_err();
                },
                _ => println!("Error"),
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What is the problem there ?
This error shows up :
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to parse: Error("EOF while parsing an object", line: 1, column: 1)', src\main.rs:30:52
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\mysqljson.exe` (exit code: 101)

Comment: Why are you trying to parse a json file line by line? It looks like there's an empty line in `info.json` is empty.

Comment: It's a common format for streamable JSON where each line is an individual record. https://jsonlines.org/ But yeah, I agree it's probably just an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a file. But serde can't figure out how to serialize that data on the file if does not exactly matches a json format.

Also, you may be aware that the OS system you're using, 'cause reading lines could making you fall of due to the `\r\n` vs `\n` differences.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In my case, there was an empty line at the end of the file (after the last line). I was splitting the entire file based on the "\n" newline character. This way the last item was an empty line and serde was trying to deserialize an empty line. hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue.
In my case, I try to read JSON file, and the problem was that it was empty, I've just added {} to the file, and this fixed my issue.
Hope it will help someone